# Windows 7 Update Installation Stuck

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

My Windows 7 Update installation is stuck after reboot. Here is the screen in front of me:

[image: Windows Update Screen]

It gets stuck here and then after a while it shutdowns and then when I restart. It processes to this level again and same things happens.

Tried getting rid of it in safe mode without success.

Comment: Tried restore option?

Answer (score 2):

Boot from a Windows 7 Sp1 DVD [into the recovery options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17101/windows-7-system-recovery-options)

[image]

and click on `Command Prompt` to start the cmd. Now run this command to stop Windows from installing the pending updates:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

and reboot the PC. Now Windows should try to revert the changes. If you're back to Windows run `sfc /scannow` or `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth` to detect issues that prevent setup of the updates.

Comment: I tried. It didn't let make do it. Finally I ended up cleaning my windows partition. And now my problem is any live linux distro I try to boot from freezes just before showing the user interface just like how Windows 7 would.

Comment: in this case do some hardware testings (CPU, memory)

Answer (score -1):

After installing updates from Windows Update, you may get into a Reboot loop 
where you machines gets to “configuring updates 3 of 3. X% complete” then freezes or reboots.

Your situation is very similar and these solutions should solve your issue.

Solution:

1a. Boot from the Windows System Repair Disc and choose the repair option in the lower left 
hand corner, choose System Restore, and select a Restore Point predating the 
attempted installation of the updates.

1b. If you don't have the DVD and Vista/W7 came preinstalled on the 
machine, use F8 at the bios splash screen to get the Windows Advanced Screen, choose "Repair Your Computer" from the list, let Windows RE load then do a system restore.

If restore fails, load the recovery environment "command prompt"
enter
Del C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml

exit recovery environment and restart the pc, you may get 3 of 3 again but be patient, the desktop should load. Create a restore point and Turn off Automatic updates until you can figure out which update caused the loop.

This is the command to run when booted offline at a recovery command prompt

dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions

This is supposed to revert all pended updates.

Comment: I did delete the pending.xml file and that didn't help and also I couldn't use the dism command on drive C:\